# raspberry pi os release 11のpip2 install numpyでエラーとなる

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python2

**問題：python2にnumpyを追加できない。**

```
$ pip2 install numpy 2>pip2.err
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.16.6.zip (5.1 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
Failed to build numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
    Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
```

実行環境：Raspberry pi os release 11にpython2を導入しています。

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.18
$ pip2 --version
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

エラーの内容：pip2.errは714行あるため途中省略とし、最初の200行と最後の100行を掲載します。

```
$ head -200 pip2.err
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-EuYogG
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/
  Complete output (346 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  blis_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
  C compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-6vbNIT/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

  creating /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/tmp
  creating /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/tmp/tmpqQ3oa0
  compile options: '-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -c'
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/source.c
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/source.o -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lcblas -o /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/a.out
  /usr/bin/ld: -lcblas が見つかりません
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/source.o -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -lblas -o /tmp/tmpqQ3oa0/a.out
  customize UnixCCompiler
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      language = c
      define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']

    FOUND:
      libraries = ['blas', 'blas']
      library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      language = c
      include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/usr/include']

  /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
  non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src

    　　・・・途中省略

    $ tail -100 pip2.err
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
    C compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-6vbNIT/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’; expected ‘double(double)’ [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
        1 | int exp (void);
          |     ^~~
    _configtest.c:1:1: note: ‘exp’ is declared in header ‘<math.h>’
      +++ |+#include <math.h>
        1 | int exp (void);
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    /usr/bin/ld: _configtest.o: in function `main':
    /tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d
    C compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-6vbNIT/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:5: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘exp’; expected ‘double(double)’ [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
        1 | int exp (void);
          |     ^~~
    _configtest.c:1:1: note: ‘exp’ is declared in header ‘<math.h>’
      +++ |+#include <math.h>
        1 | int exp (void);
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread _configtest.o -lm -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest.o.d _configtest
      adding 'build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
    building library "npysort" sources
      adding 'build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources
    Generating build/src.linux-aarch64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h
    C compiler: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-6vbNIT/python2.7-2.7.18=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: そのようなファイルやディレクトリ はありません
        1 | #include <Python.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/setup.py", line 419, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 162, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 601, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 148, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 165, in build_sources
        self.build_extension_sources(ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 322, in build_extension_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 375, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 423, in generate_config_h
        moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 47, in check_types
        out = check_types(*a, **kw)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 281, in check_types
        "install {0}-dev|{0}-devel.".format(python))
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eFE3f7/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vvBC70/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/shochou/.local/include/python2.7/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
```

参考：Ubuntu22.04(jammy)のpython2ではnumpy 1.16.6を導入できています。

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.18
$ pip2 list 2>null|grep numpy
numpy      1.16.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージ中にヒントが出ています。"Python.h" というヘッダファイルが見つからないので、python-dev または python-devel パッケージをインストールする必要がある…と言われています。
(パッケージ名は OS の種類やバージョンによって異なる場合があります)

> ```
> SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
> ```

Debian (bullseye) + Python 2.7 の場合、パッケージで検索すると以下のいずれかが該当しそうです。

- [python2.7-dev (2.7.18-8)](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python2.7-dev)
- [python2-dev (2.7.18-3)](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python2-dev)

前者の方が新しいので、以下のコマンドでパッケージをインストールした後で改めて `pip` で　Numpy のインストールを試してみてください。

```
$ sudo apt install python2.7-dev
```

Comment: 「sudo apt install python2-dev」してから再実行で正常終了しました。ヒント、ありがとうございました。